# React Native not picking functions from file directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am using react-native to build an app. The app has 2 screens: HomeScreen and Search screen. The file explorer cant find the module for Search but the same path for HomeScreen is working. Also I am using android if it helps.

**My App.js includes**:

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';


import Search from './src/screens/Search/index';

const App: () => Node = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' />
      <Search />
    </>
  );
};


export default App;
```

**Search/index.js includes**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native-vector-icons";


const Search = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hi</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

**Error:**

[image: error]

However if I replace Search by HomeScreen, the app works. Could you please help my figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using the same code and same directory search style in both my index.js files. However, I made HomeScreen/index.js before Search/index.js.

Here is my HomeScreen/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";


import HomeMap from '../../components/HomeScreenMap';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <HomeMap />
        </View>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here is my directory:

```
MEDLIFE
>__tests__
>.vscode
>android
>ios
>node_modules
>src
  >components
  >screens
    >HomeScreen
      >index.js
    >Search
      >index.js
.buckconfig
.editorconfig
.eslintrc.js
.flowconfig
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.prettierrc.js
.watchmanconfig
App.js
app.json
babel.config.js
index.js
metro.config.js
package.json
yarn.lock
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the Search component itself. Try removing the imports and returning just a fragment to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native-vector-icons";
```

To this:

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time out to help me, I don't  know how it got messed up in the post. However, my import line says import { View, Text } from "react-native"; only. It still doesn't work. I had to delete the entire project and start over again for it to work